# Minimize MAE for sum of powers

Tags: optimization

The model is
$$y_i=\beta\big(x_{i1}^\alpha+x_{i2}^\alpha+...+x_{im_i}^\alpha\big)+\epsilon_i\textrm{ for }i=1, 2, ..., n$$

 I want to minimize the MAE, i.e.
$$\Sigma_{i=1}^n{\big|y_i-\beta\big(x_{i1}^\alpha+x_{i2}^\alpha+...+x_{im_i}^\alpha\big)\big|}$$

 I tried gradient descent, but I'm worried that the solution is not a global minimum.

 Could anyone help me?